# Typing 'python' in command line will not work

Tags: python

I am new to Linux and I have downloaded Crouton on my Chromebook so that I can start learning Python. The problem is, every tutorial site tells me to type the word `python` in the terminal to start programming in Python, but when I do this it reads `command not found`.

Where do I go from here? If it helps, I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 alongside my Chrome OS.

Here is what the command line looks like:

```
(xenial)angel@localhost:~$ python
bash: python: command not found
```

Comment: Uhm, Ubuntu doesn't work without Python, so this is pretty strange. Could you please edit your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -l python-minimal python2.7-minimal` and `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand, should I type that line in to the terminal?

Comment: Yes, please open a terminal, type the command(s), copy and paste their output into the question.

Comment: The first line came as command not found, the second line has an output with dates such as 9 mar 23 2016 /usr:bin/python3 -> python3.5

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the full outputs there. Also add the output of `echo $PATH` please.

Comment: No `dpkg-query` either? Things are getting weirder… Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `apt-get install -f ubuntu-desktop`? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have just helped me solved the problem. Seeing "python3.5" in the output gave me an idea and instead of typing python I typed 'python3' in to the command line and it seems to have worked

Comment: No, the problem is not solved yet. `python` must be Python 2 and `python3` must be Python 3. Ubuntu requires both versions to be present, as the versions are not fully compatible and some scripts are written for one and some for the other. Also if you learn Python 2, you can not run these scripts on the Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: understood, here is the full output                lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460336 Nov 17 14:23 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460336 Nov 17 14:23 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m

Comment: @PadawanAngel don't include the info necessary to answer your question in the comments, [edit] your question instead.